# NSPredicate with a NSArray of NSNumbers (Core Data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have Core Data entity Field with an attribute of `ID`. I want to search all Field entities for ID == 1, 2, or 3.

How can I add an array to a NSPredicate w/out creating a long appended string something like:

```
NSArray *IDArray = @[@1, @2, @3];

NSMutableString *predicateString = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSNumber *ID in IDArray) {
    [predicateString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID == %@, ID]];
}
```

Comment: Just as a note - normal Objective-C convention would have instance and local variables begin with a lower-case letter. That makes your code snippets easier to read for other people.

Comment: xCode will assume `id` is a class type. And I've been under the impression abbreviations should be capitalized? I guess IDArray makes sense to me. Should I rename so the name doesn't start with a capitalized abbreviation, such as `arrayOfIDs`?

Comment: That is a question of personal taste, I believe. I admit to type it out as `ident` or `identifier`, making the compiler happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSArray *IDArray = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID IN %@", IDArray];
```

*Remark:* You should never use string formatting functions to combine predicates. Use

```
 [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:...]
```

and similar methods. The reason is that strings and predicates have different rules how format specifiers are expanded.

Comment: Ok, I saw this used with strings, I wasn't sure if it would work for NSNumbers as well, thanks!

Comment: @Log139: It works even if the attribute has Integer type, and the array contains strings: the types are converted as necessary. - Please consider to "accept" the answer if it helped, thank you.

Comment: I tried to accept the first time, told me to wait 30 seconds so started coding again and forgot to come back to accept =D